# scrollToRowAtIndexPath does not offset to specific cell

Tags: uitableview

I have a tableview and each cell is of the size of the screen. Paging is enabled. I'm using the following code to show a specific cell when the tableview is loaded:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:picID] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [URLstringArrays count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

I'm passing on the picID from another controller  but the tableview does not start on the specified section. Any ideas of what might be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Has the table even been loaded? Try scrolling in `viewWillAppear:` / `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: Same behavior if I scroll in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. It always shows the 1st row. I implement uitableviewController in the .h file so I guess it was supposed to work this way.